# Cordova Battery Status and Network Connetion in Ionic 2 Application?

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am new to Ionic framework.

- I am trying to display `network connection and battery status in my app home page`. as of now we got `network connection` solution. but we struggling to display `battery status` Can someone please provide me how to show the device battery status in a Ionic 2 application? I found the `cordovaBatteryStatus` plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status.
- I have installed the plugin,

**My home.html:-**

```
<h2>Battery status: {{batteryStatus}}</h2>
<ion-content class="home" padding>
    <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="checkNetwork()" full>Get Nettwork Connection</button>
</ion-content>
```

**My home.ts :-**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { BatteryStatus } from 'ionic-native';

declare var batteryLevel: any;
declare var navigator: any;
declare var Connection: any;



@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  hideTopTab:boolean=true;
   x(){
 console.log(this.hideTopTab);

    this.hideTopTab = !this.hideTopTab;
}

// hideBottomTab:boolean=true;
//    y(){
//  console.log(this.hideBottomTab);

//     this.hideBottomTab = !this.hideBottomTab;
// }
status:any;
  constructor(public alert:AlertController , public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
  let subscription = BatteryStatus.onChange().subscribe( (status) => { 
    console.log(status.level, status.isPlugged); 
    this.status=status.level;
    } );
   } );

  }

  onBatteryStatus(info){
  alert('battery status: '+info.level+' isPlugged: '+info.isPlugged);
  batteryLevel = info.level;
}

checkNetwork() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
            let alert = this.alert.create({
                title: "Connection Status",
                subTitle: states[networkState],
                buttons: ["OK"]
            });
            alert.present();
        });
    }
}
```

- The above codes are used to display the `Battery Status and Device Network connection`. But `Network Connection` is working perfectly it's displaying the `Device Network connection`.
- We have done almost we trying to display `Device Battery Status and Network Connection`, As of now we got the `network connection` solution, but now we struggling to get the `battery status` solution....
- So please can you check my codes and provide the exact solution, we don't know where we did the mistake  in `home.ts and home.html`. Thank you in advance...

Comment: put the call within platform.ready()

Comment: are you getting any logs?

Comment: No ...check my home.ts and home.html for reference...thanks for your comment...

Comment: You have the wrong idea..You are adding a handler to onChange event.. It will fire only when battery status changes..It may not print on every button click..

Comment: ok fine if you know the solution let us help....we want to do `battery status` in my app so please help us....thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong idea..You are adding a handler to `onChange` event. It will fire only when battery status changes..It may not print on every button click.
All it does is replace the event listener on every button click
Have a class variable `status`

In the constructor subscribe within `platform.ready()` and set the status variable in callback. 
You could show the status value in alert on button click.

```
    status:any;
        constructor(public alert:AlertController , public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) { 
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
    let subscription = BatteryStatus.onChange().subscribe( (status) => { 
    console.log(status.level, status.isPlugged); 
    this.status=status.level;
    } );
   } );
}
```

Depending on how you would like to show battery status,

```
<h2>Battery status: {{status?.level}}</h2>
<h2>Battery is plugged:{{status?.isPlugged}}</h2>
```

Since status is set asynchronously use `?` as a check for `undefined`.Value will be updated once changed.

Comment: no problem..or instead of constructor you could also set the callback in `ngOninit` hook

Comment: hi suraj we got error in `this.status = status.level;` so please check and update....even me too debugging the error...

Comment: you need to declare status as class variable as I mentioned

Comment: I am not able to see qny screenshot..what error are you getting?

Comment: now i have updated my screenshot on above please look at and help us...

Comment: not a big issue..its a simple case of missing bracket or paranthesis..will update snippet..was typing from cellphone

Comment: try now..and let me know

Comment: Hi Suraj  I am sorry  if i declare status as variable like as you mentioned we got again more errors i have updated the screen shot on above....is there any thing i need to remove or add in home.ts? and what kind of code i need to add in home.html ....thanks

Comment: sry.. for a class variable declare without let. Also since you are setting platform parameter with public scope there is no need to set in the constructor again

Comment: yeah thanks suraj the status error is solved, is there any thing i need to add in html part?.. and i have updated my home.ts also in above questions...thanks...

Comment: Hi suraj sorry for again asking help to you, if i used your html code i got some error like `level is undefined` we tried to solve this error but we unable to solve the issue....please help us... thanks

Comment: suraj if you dont' mind can you just clone this link:- git clone https://maniselvam@bitbucket.org/maniselvam/ionic2battery.git  for  the `battery status` solution ....because we  have tried lot to get the solution but we have't got the solution...please check and update.....actually we don't know where we did the mistake....thanks

Comment: Hi suraj have you cloned the link ?... any updates still i am waiting for your valuable solution.....please help me thanks

Comment: I am not sure..I am not able to work on your code. If you have any specific question you could create a question

Comment: you unable to clone or what suraj? you just copy past this link :- git clone maniselvam@bitbucket.org/maniselvam/ionic2battery.git in your terminal suraj... if unale to clone let me know i will ask specific question

Comment: I dunno what else issue  is there.you will have to work on it.. Good luck

Comment: Now i have updated the error screen shot on above please check and update if you knows the solution...thanks...

Comment: that simply means you are not using the imported class in your file. It is a warning not an error.

Answer (score 0):

- For the **Network connection⚡️** you could use https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/
- For the **Battery status**  you could use https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/battery-status/
- For the **Other diagnostics ‍⚕️** you could use https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/diagnostic/

Note that the plugins aren't bound to Ionic 2 you could use them in other Cordova projects as well.